# Adjoint sensitivity analysis for a cost functional under an ODE constraint

Tags: machine-learning, derivations

I am trying to recover the result given by equation 10 in the article [here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/lu20b/lu20b.pdf). I am unable to get rid of the integral, any help would be much appreciated. To keep the description as self contained as possible, I will describe the relevant notations etc., a more detailed reference is the article [1](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/lu20b/lu20b.pdf) itself. Here is my attempt:

Suppose, the overparametrized deep ResNet is modeled via a mean-field ODE:

$$
 \dot{X_\rho}(x,t)=\int_{\theta}f(X_{\rho}(x,t),\theta)\rho(\theta,t)d\theta.
$$

Here $x$ denotes the input at the layer $t=0$ and $X_{\rho}(x,1)$ is the output at the final layer $t=1$.
In this model, every residual block $f(\cdot,\theta_i)$ is considered as a particle and optimization (training) will be done over the distribution of the particles $\rho(\theta,t)$ where $\theta$ denotes the parameters of the Residual block and $t$ denotes the $t-th$ layer of the block. We will further represent $\int_{\theta}f(X_{\rho}(x,t),\theta)\rho(\theta, t)d\theta= F(X_{\rho}(x,t);\rho)$. We also know that $\rho(\theta, t)$ is a density for every $t$. Thus the ODE equation above is is reduced to:

$\dot{X_\rho}(x,t)=F(X_{\rho}(x,t);\rho).$

Let $E(x,\rho)$ be the cost function that depends on the mismatch of the output of the neural net, $X_{\rho}(x,1)$, and the true output $y(x)$. For emphasis we note that $X_{\rho}(x,1)$ is the final output of the neural net at layer $t=1$ corresponding to the true input $x$. Now we calculate the sensitivity of the cost function $E(x,\rho)$ with respect to the parameter $\rho(\theta,t)$ that describes the distribution of the weight parameters $\theta$ at every $t-$th layer of the neural net. We will sometimes supress the explicit dependence of $E(x,\rho)$ on its arguments and simply write $E:=E(x,\rho)$ for convenience.

$\frac{dE(x,\rho)}{d\rho}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,1)}\frac{d X_{\rho}(x,1)}{d \rho}.$

To calculate $\frac{d X_{\rho}(x,1)}{d \rho}$ we will use the adjoint sensitivity method.
Recall:

$ X_{\rho}(x,1)=x+\int_{0}^1 F(X_{\rho}(x,t);\rho) dt$

$ \frac{d X_{\rho}(x,1)}{d\rho}=\int_{0}^1 \bigg[\frac{\partial {F(X_{\rho}(x,t);\rho)}}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,t)}\frac{d{X_{\rho}(x,t)}}{d \rho}+\frac{\partial F(X_{\rho}(x,t);\rho)}{\partial \rho}\bigg]dt-\int_{0}^1 \lambda(t) \bigg[\frac{d \dot{X_\rho}(x,t)}{d\rho}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,t) }\frac{{d X_{\rho}(x,t) }}{d \rho}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho}\bigg]$.

Note that the second integral is zero due to the ODE equation above. More specifically, $\frac{d}{d\rho}\bigg(\dot{X_\rho}(x,t)-F(X_{\rho}(x,t);\rho)\bigg)=0$.

Consider the term
$-\int_{0}^1 \lambda (t)\frac{d \dot{X_\rho}(x,t)}{d\rho} dt=-\int_{0}^1 \lambda (t)\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d {X_\rho}(x,t)}{d\rho} dt$
Evaluating using integration by parts

$-\int_{0}^1 \lambda (t)\frac{d \dot{X_\rho}(x,t)}{d\rho} dt=-\lambda(t) \frac{d X_{\rho}(x,t)}{d\rho}|_{t=0}^{t=1}
+\int_0^1 \frac{d\lambda (t)}{dt} \frac{d X\rho}{d\rho} dt $

We will choose $\lambda$ such that $\lambda(1)=0$. We also note that $\frac{dX_{\rho}}{d\rho}|_{t=0}=0$.

Using these we can rewrite,

$ \frac{d X_{\rho}(x,1)}{d\rho}=\int_{0}^1 \bigg[(\lambda(t)+Id)\frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,t)}+\frac{d\lambda(t)}{dt}\bigg]\frac{d X_{\rho}(x,t)}{d\rho} dt+\int_{0}^1 (\lambda+Id)\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} $

Now we choose $\lambda(t)$ to satisfy the ODE equation:
$(\lambda(t)+Id)\frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,t)}+\frac{d\lambda(t)}{dt}=0$
along with the condition $\lambda(1)=0$. This is equivalent to the system for $\tilde{\lambda}=\lambda+Id$,

$-\tilde{\lambda}(t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,t)}=\frac{d\tilde{\lambda}(t)}{dt} $
and $\tilde{\lambda}(1)=Id$.

It can be independently verified that $\tilde{\lambda}(t)=J_{\rho}(x,t)$ where $J_{\rho}(x,t)=\frac{d X_{\rho}(x,1)}{d  X_{\rho}(x,t)}$ satisfies the system along with final value at $t=1$, see also [1](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/lu20b/lu20b.pdf)(eqn 9).

Thus we get,
$\frac{d X_{\rho}(x,1)}{d\rho}=\int_{0}^1 J_{\rho}(x,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} dt$ and so,

$\frac{dE(x,\rho)}{d\rho}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,1)} \int_{0}^1 J_{\rho}(x,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} dt$

whereas in the article, [1](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/lu20b/lu20b.pdf)(eqn 10), it is evaluated:

$\frac{dE(x,\rho)}{d\rho}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial X_{\rho}(x,1)}  J_{\rho}(x,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, that is just about the meaning of the expression $\frac{\partial E(x,\rho)}{\partial\rho}$. Since $\rho$ is *a function* of $t$, it really means "a function $D(t)$ such that
$$
E(x,\rho+\Delta\rho)-E(x,\rho)\approx \int_0^1 D(t)\Delta\rho(t)\,dt
$$
for all small perturbations $\Delta\rho(t)$".

What you did was to compute the derivative treating $\rho$ like a constant, i.e., your computation is formally valid assuming $\Delta\rho(t)=h$ throughout the whole interval, in which case your formula is just a partial case of their formula, i.e.,
$$
E(x,\rho+h)-E(x,\rho)\approx h\int_0^1 D(t)\,dt.
$$
However you derivation is incomplete because you need to find the linearization for *all* $\Delta\rho$, not just constants. Fortunately, you hardly need to change anything in it: almost mechanical insertion of $\Delta\rho$ where it belongs should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, Fedja! Could you elaborate a little however? Should I be calculating $X_{\rho+d\rho}-X_{\rho}=\int_{0}^1 F(X_{\rho+d\rho}(x,t);\rho+d\rho)-F(X_{\rho};\rho) dt$
I am unsure how to do that, I thought the adjoint method would be useful, but I am unable to get rid of the integral. Do they mean the derivative to be taken with respect to $\rho_t=\rho(\cdot,t)$ for some given $t$?

Comment: @Abhi.A You don't need to get rid of the integral at all, that's the whole point! On the contrary, you should get the linearized (in $\Delta\rho$) expression for the increment of the final output as $\int_0^1 D(t)\Delta\rho(t)\,dt$ and then you'll be able to claim (see the definition I provided) that the derivative of a certain functional with respect to the function argument is $D(t)$. That claim *includes* integration, if you expand the corresponding definition, which I provided. It is just not written explicitly in that shorthand notation.

Comment: @Abhi.A To simplify the matters and to relate it to something you know, let's say we have a real valued function $G(z)$ of an $n$-dimensional vector $z=(z_1,\dots,z_n)$. Then one can write $\frac{dG}{dz}=w=(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ (which is nothing but the gradient vector in a fancy notation) or one can write $G(z+dz)-G(z)\approx \sum_j w_j\, dz_j$. The first formula has no sum symbol in it, the second does, but it is the same statement!

Comment: Thanks! that is very useful!

Comment: @Abhi.A Exactly like that :-) Only I would add parentheses:  $(dX_{\rho}(x,1)/d\rho)(t)$ not to confuse the reader about which function takes $t$ as an argument on the LHS.

Comment: Thanks Fedja! It makes much more sense now. That was super helpful -- just one last thing, is there a reference I could cite for the definition that you gave?

Comment: @Abhi.A That is a common thing. Try some book in variational calculus. Technically it is a combination of two things: 1) The derivative with respect to a function argument is formally a linear functional on the corresponding linear space of admissible perturbations and 2) Most of the time (but not always!) that linear functional can be written as an integral against another function, which, in that case, is identified with the notation $\frac{dX}{d\rho}$ or something like that.